# Java custom checkerboard with nested loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to make a custom checkboard with given user input, in the form of (# of rows, # of columns, size of each square, filler character).
I've made my loop, but I am unable to get more then a 1 1 1 checkerboard properly.
I am stuck on how to divide the filler characters to make the individual squares rather than the characters becoming lines like they are now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Checker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int col, row, size;
        char filler;
        System.out.println("Please enter 3 numbers and a character."); //output
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //input

        row = scan.nextInt();
        col = scan.nextInt();
        size = scan.nextInt();
        filler = scan.next().charAt(0);  // defined variables

        int r, c, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        for (r = 1; r <= row; r++) {
            for (c = 1; c <= col; c++) {
                do {
                    if ((r % 2 != 0 && c % 2 != 0) || (r % 2 == 0 && c % 2 == 0)) {
                        do {
                            System.out.print(filler);
                            i++;
                        }
                        while (i < size);
                        i = 0;

                    } else {
                        do {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                            j++;
                        }
                        while (j < size);
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    k++;
                } while (k < size);
                k = 0;

            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("\nHave a nice day. Goodbye.");

    }
}


3 3 3 x would give:
    xxx  xxx
    xxx  xxx 
    xxx  xxx 
       xxx  
       xxx  
       xxx  
    xxx  xxx  
    xxx  xxx   
    xxx  xxx
```

Comment: The problem seams to be the first do-while. What exactly is `k` used for?

Comment: Thanks, I took that out but how would I duplicate the lines now to make them squares?

Comment: could you explain what you mean by squares? perhaps include some manually typed in input of what you would like it to look like?

Comment: 3 3 3 x would output 3 rows and 3 columns of 3 by 3 squares, I included it in my original post editted

Comment: can you put that as `code` in your question so that the formatting stays consistent? Thanks.

Comment: Done, it's in the question. Fixed it again, the dimensions were off, sorry

Comment: Ok I now understand the `k`. It just needs to be moved up. I will edit my answer below to reflect.

Comment: I removed the K entirely, but you're basically just going to need to iterate SIZE times in each row before moving to the next row. Print out the top line of row 1, then the next line etc, until the top row is SIZE in height before processing the next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first do-while is just embedded to far. It should come before the second for loop. Also, I removed the "\n" inside of println. You might have wanted it that way, im not sure.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Checker{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int col, row, size; char filler;
    System.out.println("Please enter 3 numbers and a character."); //output
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //input

    row = scan.nextInt();
    col = scan.nextInt();
    size = scan.nextInt();
    filler = scan.next().charAt(0);  // defined variables

    int r,c,i=0,j=0,k=0;

    for (r=1; r<=row; r++) {
      do {
        for (c=1; c<=col; c++){
          if ((r % 2 != 0 && c % 2 !=0) || (r %2 == 0 && c % 2 == 0)){
            do {
              System.out.print(filler);
              i++;
            }
            while (i<size);
            i = 0;

          }


          else {
            do
            {  System.out.print(" ");
              j++;
            }
            while (j<size);
            j = 0;
          }
        }
        k++;
        System.out.println();
      }
      while (k < size);
      k = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("\nHave a nice day. Goodbye.");
  }

}
```

with the input `3 3 3 X`
produced the following.

```
XXX   XXX
XXX   XXX
XXX   XXX
   XXX   
   XXX   
   XXX   
XXX   XXX
XXX   XXX
XXX   XXX
```

The output doesnt match what you wanted. But I believe it is correct because it is 3X3. If you want to change it you just need to increase the length of the row. (increase the # of columns)

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. Your logic fails when printing the boxes. You currently have it printing the filler SIZE times until it's done, then it prints the spaces etc. But the problem is that you don't move to the next line until you're done with that row. In reality you need to process the first row in several lines, moving to a new line SIZE times printing values before moving to the next row.

I've taken the liberty of finishing this for you as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{ 

public static void main(String[] args) {
int col, row, size; char filler;
System.out.println("Please enter 3 numbers and a character."); //output
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //input

row = scan.nextInt();
col = scan.nextInt();
size = scan.nextInt();
filler = scan.next().charAt(0);  // defined variables

int r,c,i=0,j=0,k=0;

for(r=1; r<=row; r++){
    for(int boxSize = 0; boxSize < size; boxSize++){
        for(c=1; c<=col; c++){

                if((r % 2 != 0 && c%2 !=0) || (r % 2 == 0 && c % 2 == 0)){
                    do{
                        System.out.print(filler);
                        i++;
                    }
                    while(i < size);
                    i = 0;
                }
                else{
                    do{
                        System.out.print(" ");
                        j++;
                    }
                    while(j < size);
                    j = 0;
                }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
System.out.println("\nHave a nice day. Goodbye.");
}
}
```